# Iphone mpmediaplayerController, unable to restart video after user presses done

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, media-player

I'm having trouble with Iphone's mediaplayercontroller.

I'm able to play the video once, with no problems.

When the user presses done, I close the mediaplayer, and move my user back to the previous screen. (I'm using a navigation based application).

However, when I try to start the video again by pressing the play button, the mediaplayercontroller no longer works correctly.

All I get is a black screen. No video, no sounds.

I've already released the previous mediaplayper controller after getting the MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification or the MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

More Info-------
Here is a snippet of my code:

```
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url]; 
[self.view addSubview:moviePlayerController.view]; 

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self  
                                         selector:@selector(moviePlaybackComplete:)  
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification  
                                           object:nil];  

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self  
                                         selector:@selector(moviePlaybackComplete:)  
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification  
                                           object:nil];  // This is to deal with the user pressing the done button.

[moviePlayerController setFullscreen:YES];
[moviePlayerController play];

}

- (void)moviePlaybackComplete:(NSNotification *)notification  
{  
NSLog(@"movie playback ended");
int reason = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishReasonUserInfoKey] intValue];
if(reason == MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackEnded)
    NSLog(@"Reason: MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackEnded");
else if(reason == MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackError)
    NSLog(@"Reason: MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackError");
else if(reason == MPMovieFinishReasonUserExited)
    NSLog(@"Reason: MPMovieFinishReasonUserExited");
else
    NSLog(@"Reason: %d", reason);

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self  
                                                name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification  
                                              object:nil];  

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self  
                                                name:MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification  
                                              object:nil];  

[moviePlayerController.view removeFromSuperview]; 
moviePlayerController.initialPlaybackTime = -1; 
[moviePlayerController pause];
[moviePlayerController stop];
[moviePlayerController release]; 
moviePlayerController = nil;

[[self navigationController] popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: You mentioned releasing the player, so just to be sure, you are creating a new instance right? I would also check to make sure the MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinish notification is actually being called.

Comment: MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification is called when I press the done button.

As you can see, I've created an new instance of mediaplayer whenever I try to play a new video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-(void)videoFile:(NSString *)moviepath
{

    //[tools setHidden:YES];
//  bi3.enabled=NO;

    // Register to receive a notification when the movie scaling mode has changed. 


    //NSString *moviePath = [bundle pathForResource:@"video" ofType:@"mp4"];
    NSURL  *movieURL1 = [[NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviepath] retain];
    MPMoviePlayerController *theMovie = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL1];
    [theMovie setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen];
    [theMovie play];
    MPMoviePlayerViewController *moviePlayer11 = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL1];
    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:moviePlayer11];  // Override point for customization after app launch    
    // [navigationController.view addSubview:];
    //[self.view addSubview:mpMCtr.view];



}
- (void) movieFinishedCallback:(NSNotification*) aNotification 
{
    bi3.enabled=YES;
    [tools setHidden:NO];
    MPMoviePlayerController *player = [aNotification object];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
     removeObserver:self
     name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
     object:player];
   // [player stop];
    //[self.view removeFromSuperview];
[player.view removeFromSuperview];

       [player autorelease];    
}

- (void) moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{

    MPMoviePlayerController* theMovie=[aNotification object]; 
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self 
                                                    name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                                  object:theMovie];
    //[mpMCtr stop];

    [theMovie.view removeFromSuperview];
    [videoTable removeFromSuperview];


    //[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

-(void)videoClick:(id)sender
{
    bi3.enabled=NO;
    path2 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Interview" ofType:@"mp4" inDirectory:nil];
    [self videoFile:path2];

}
```